# onSomeEventListener crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have set up an application with a main activity and 2 fragment activities. I use a onsomeevent to pass data from the fragment to the main activity. The first fragment works fine and passes data. There is only one fragment running at a time.  I copied the same event listener to second fragment but it crashes with "" must implement onSomeEventListener".  I am stuck.

the main activity class I implement the listener

```
    public class SimpleRGB_Main extends FragmentActivity implements onSomeEventListener {
```

I also capture the data passed from the first fragment slider controls

```
    // Return event for RGB controls.
@Override
public void someEvent(int FixtureNumber, int R_value, int G_value, int B_value) {
    }
```

The first fragment is called slider controls

```
     public class SliderControls extends Fragment {

public interface onSomeEventListener {
    public void someEvent(int position, int R_Value, int G_value, int B_value);
}

onSomeEventListener someEventListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        someEventListener = (onSomeEventListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onSomeEventListener");
    }
}
```

Second fragment

```
    public class ButtonControls extends Fragment {


public interface onSomeEventListener {
    public void someEvent(int position, int R_Value, int G_value, int B_value);
}

onSomeEventListener someEventListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        someEventListener = (onSomeEventListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onSomeEventListener");
    }
}
```

Here are the changed I made. I separated the listener and renamed them to make them easy to follow. In main activity.

```
        // Return event for RGB controls.
@Override
public void onFragmentSliderDoSomething(int FixtureNumber, int R_value, int G_value, int B_value) {

     public void onFragmentButtonsDoSomething(int FixtureNumber, int R_value, int G_value, int B_value) {
```

Also in the main activity be sure to implement both listeners

```
    public class SimpleRGB_Main extends FragmentActivity implements SliderControls.FragmentAListener, ButtonControls.FragmentBListener {
```

In Button Fragment

```
    public class ButtonControls extends Fragment {

private FragmentBListener someEventListener;

public interface FragmentBListener {
    public void onFragmentButtonsDoSomething(int position, int R_Value, int G_value, int B_value);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        someEventListener = (FragmentBListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onSomeEventListener");
    }
}
```

In Slider Fragment

```
    public class SliderControls extends Fragment {

private FragmentAListener someEventListener;

public interface FragmentAListener {
    public void onFragmentSliderDoSomething(int position, int R_Value, int G_value, int B_value);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        someEventListener = (FragmentAListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onSomeEventListener");
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have set up an application with a main activity and 2 fragment activities." As you mentioned, you have more then one activities, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two separate interfaces, one for one Fragment, then another for the other Fragment. Give them separate names like onFragmentAListener and on FragmentBListener, as well as change the onAttach's to correspond to the correct interfaces. Then implement both interfaces with the main activity.

Each fragment will look something like this:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private FragmentAListener mCallback;

    public interface FragmentAListener {
        onFragmentADoSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach (Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (FragmentAListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement FragmentAListener");
        }
    }

    //where ever you need to do the callback...
    mCallback.onFragmentADoSomething();

    }
```

In the main activity, do something like this:

```
public class Main_Activity extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentA.FragmentAListener, FragmentB.FragmentBListener{


    @Override
    public void someEvent(int FixtureNumber, int R_value, int G_value, int B_value) {
    // whatever you have it doing here
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentAListener (int FixtureNumber, int R_value, int G_value, int B_value) {
    someEvent(...);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentBListener (int FixtureNumber, int R_value, int G_value, int B_value) {
    someEvent(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still a little confused. You got me in the right direction. Do I need to implement both A and B in the main activity or does onSomeEventListener implement both ? in the fragment I just changed the someEventListenerA = (onSomeEventListenerA) activity; then fragment B is someEventListenerB = (onSomeEventListenerB) activity;

Comment: anyone have an example using on communicating with 2 fragments. Its the onAttach() and how to separate the A and B listeners.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation; all of your fragments check if activities have implemented `onSomeEventListener` interface (fragments check this at their `onAttach` method). So your error can only happen when an activity tries to add a fragment but it have not implemented `onSomeEventListener` interface.

Check your activities those add your fragments. There are some of them which haven't implenented `onSomeEventListener` interface.